# How to manage dividers in a PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-preferences

I started dealing with preferences in a `PreferenceFragment`. Here's what I have:

[image: my_preferences]

I'm trying to:

1. get rid of the dividers between items. I suppose this can be defined from styles, but I can't figure out how. I tried getting the
   preference `ListView` at runtime calling
   `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`, as I read somewhere, but it
   returns null.
2. set new, **full width** dividers right on top of the headers, as seen [**here**](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7b0NpckxqVnBxbWs/components_lists_keylines_two3.png). For example in this case I want a full width divider right above "Statistiche", but not above "Generali" which is on top of the list.

The only way that comes to my mind is setting dividers as fake preferences, like with:

```
<Preference
    android:layout="@layout/divider" //here I set width and a divider resource
    />

<PreferenceCategory ... />
```

The main issue here is that my `PreferenceFragment` (or the `ActionBarActivity` it's in) has some left/right padding, that make any divider I add into preferences.xml **not** cover the entire width.

So my question are:

- How can I get rid of default, item-item dividers that you can see in the image?
- How can I set full width dividers right above headers, or how can I get rid of internal fragment/activity padding? Of course my activity layout has no (explicit) padding whatsoever.

Comment: Hi, did u get the answer?. can you help with the solution if you have?

Comment: @Naruto in short I used `list = findViewById(android.R.id.list)` and then `list.setDivider(null)`. To avoid NPE, you need to call this `onResume` rather than `onCreate`. As for the other issue, I will try to post a full answer today.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. I'm using fragments not an activity. i.e my class looks like `public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment`. So in this case how can we achieve? any help.

Comment: `getview()` returns me NULL, if i call `View rootView = getView();` like this

Comment: @Naruto see my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had totally forgot about this question, will post an answer now to help others. I solved by moving my code in the `onResume()` method of the activity that hosts my `PreferenceFragment`. I think there are several other points at which you can recall a non-null `ListView` using `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`.

```
public boolean mListStyled;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!mListStyled) {
        View rootView = getView();
        if (rootView != null) {
            ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            list.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            list.setDivider(null);
            //any other styling call
            mListStyled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can probably get rid of the `rootView` check, but at the same time you might even want to check for `list != null`. I didn't face any NPE this way anyway.

So, `setDivider(null)` takes off the item-item dividers. I managed to add section dividers covering the full width of the screen by:

- Removing padding from `list`;
- Adding a custom preference in my XML:

n

```
 <Preference
     android:title="divider"
     android:selectable="false"
     android:layout="@layout/preference_divider"/>
```

Comment: I did it, but not show divider inside list, pls help me. thanks!

Comment: after API 21 a recyclerview is returned, if 'android.R.id.list' will be searched. setDivider(null) in onStart of PreferenceFragmentCompat should help.

Comment: Can you maybe share your `preference_divider.xml` ?

Comment: Sorry @Zoker , I can't

Answer (score 58):

**AndroidX** makes it simple, but I wish it was better documented.

**In XML**

To add/remove dividers between preferences in XML, use the following attributes:

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Preference
        ...
        app:allowDividerAbove="true/false"
        app:allowDividerBelow="true/false"
        ... />

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Note, a divider will only be shown between two preferences if the top divider has `allowDividerBelow` set to `true` and the bottom divider has `allowDividerAbove` set to `true`.

**In Code**

You can also change/remove dividers programmatically using the following methods in `onActivityCreated` of your `PreferenceFragmentCompat`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // To remove:
    setDivider(null);

    // To change:
    setDivider(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.your_drawable));
    setDividerHeight(your_height);
}
```

Comment: Good answer: Quick questions: 1. Do you know how to make the dividers appear in the layout preview of Android Studio? 2. Is there a way to call `setDivider()` in an XML theme, rather than in code? For item 2, I've tried `"android:listDivider"` and `"android:divider"` everywhere, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 28):

Add this code under the `PreferenceFragment` :

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // remove dividers
        View rootView = getView();
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setDivider(null);

    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Quick, easy, short. Every other answer (That didn't even work) that I've come across seemed excessive. Thanks!

Comment: do we have to create a list view then set each element as layout for the same?!

Comment: After ANDROID 21 a RecyclerView is used to display the list-based content, so the R.id.list delieveres a RecyclerView reference, which can't be handled the same way we did with ListView.

Comment: @Fattum that's not what I'm experiencing...  maybe it depends on the type of preference used?  normal vs support v4 etc.?

Comment: @CamHart what exacatly, you are not experiencing?

Comment: @Fattum I'm using android > 21 and R.id.list still works.

Comment: For SDK 21 and below. the code works within onCreateView. For SDK 23, it only works within onActivityCreated. BTW, if you are getting RecyclerView, perhaps you are using the support library, which has it's own setDivider methods.

Answer (score 11):

Although a bit late I`m having same troubles with dividers in preff screen and found this solution:
Set custom style to the hosting activity and add to the style:

```
   <item name="android:listDivider">@null</item>
```

It actually does the same as setting it trough code but you save one findById and i think it looks clearer set trough styles

Comment: Awesome. The easiest one.

Comment: The best solution since it also accounts for subscreens.

Answer (score 4):

For PreferenceFragmentCompat, ListView doesn't work.
But this works like a charm:

```
<style name="PrefsTheme" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Add this to your app theme:

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PrefsTheme</item>
```

Comment: There is no such parent "PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material"

Comment: Uh, sorry, you have to add dependency to build.gradle first. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34220290/1259029

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem and wanted dividers between preference categories but not between the items themselves. I found that the accepted solution satisfied Question 1 by removing the dividers from preference items but did not fix question 2 and add the dividers between preference categories.

Fix below. 
Basically override the onCreateAdapter method of your PreferenceFragmentCompat and give it a custom PreferenceGroupAdapter that has an overridden onBindViewHolder method that uses the position and whatever else you need to set above and below permissions for each view holder. A divider will be drawn when both viewholders allow a divider between them.

Here is my fix

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    protected RecyclerView.Adapter onCreateAdapter(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen) {
        return new CustomPreferenceGroupAdapter(preferenceScreen);
    }

    static class CustomPreferenceGroupAdapter extends PreferenceGroupAdapter {

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public CustomPreferenceGroupAdapter(PreferenceGroup preferenceGroup) {
        super(preferenceGroup);
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder, int position) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
        Preference currentPreference = getItem(position);
        //For a preference category we want the divider shown above.
        if(position != 0 && currentPreference instanceof PreferenceCategory) {
            holder.setDividerAllowedAbove(true);
            holder.setDividerAllowedBelow(false);
        } else {
            //For other dividers we do not want to show divider above 
            //but allow dividers below for CategoryPreference dividers.
            holder.setDividerAllowedAbove(false);
            holder.setDividerAllowedBelow(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**(AndroidX only)**

[Maksim Ivanov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55981453/920849) got me most of the way there.  But to remove dividers **only for a specific Preference** created in code, I had to do:

```
val pref = object : Preference(activity) {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder)
        // By default, preferences created in code show dividers
        holder.setDividerAllowedAbove(false)
        holder.setDividerAllowedBelow(false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use a PreferenceFragment ,you can use ListView.`setDivider(null)`;
if you use a PreferenceFragmentCompat ,you can use PreferenceFragmentCompat.`setDivider(Drawable divider)` or `setDividerHeight(int height)`;

Answer (score 0):

New solution for new android API 24 and above (**December 25th, 2017**).

I've found after try many ways on stackoverflow, but not work, or it just work but not work in **nestest** `PreferenceScreen`.

Frist, you need to find listview from current displaying fragment, and remove the divider:

```
private fun removeDividerInCurrentFragment() {
    this@YourPreferenceActivity.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content)?.let {
        it.view?.findViewById<ListView?>(android.R.id.list)?.let {
            it.divider = null
            it.dividerHeight = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Second, to remove the divider when fragment commited, call method above (`removeDividerInCurrentFragment`) to remove listview's divider.

To sure if you have **nestest `PreferenceScreen`**. Register listener when fragment changed in your `PreferenceActivity` by implement `FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener` protocol:

```
class YourPreferenceActivity : PreferenceActivity(), FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {
    override fun onBackStackChanged() {
        this@YourPreferenceActivity.removeDividerInCurrentFragment()
    }
}
```

Finally, register backstack changes listener by call `fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this@ YourPreferenceActivity)` in `onCreate`. And remove backstack changes listener by call `fragmentManager.removeOnBackStackChangedListener` in `onDestroyed` method.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can re-style your divider using this theme.

```
<style name="PreferenceFragment.Material">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/preference_list_divider_material</item>
</style>
```