# How to style PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-settings

I'm using a `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, but I don't think it is styled correctly.

[image]

Preferences' title seems way to big, PreferenceCategory text is unreadable, the whole think seems off.

This is what I have in theme.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="preferenceScreenStyle">@style/Preference.PreferenceScreen</item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentStyle">@style/PreferenceFragment</item>
    <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/Preference.Category</item>
    <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/Preference</item>
    <item name="preferenceInformationStyle">@style/Preference.Information</item>
    <item name="checkBoxPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.CheckBoxPreference</item>
    <item name="switchPreferenceCompatStyle">@style/Preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat</item>
    <item name="dialogPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference</item>
    <item name="editTextPreferenceStyle">@style/Preference.DialogPreference.EditTextPreference
    </item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentListStyle">@style/PreferenceFragmentList</item>
</style>
```

Comment: https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52960668/4310905 for a solution to fix all preferences at once

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Following [this](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix).

Change

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
```

to

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
```

Then, change in `build.gradle` dependencies

```
com.android.support:preference-v7
```

to

```
com.android.support:preference-v14
```

Comment: This solution does not support SDK < 14.

Comment: I think that, com.android.support:preference-v14 should be an addition to com.android.support:preference-v7 It is not a replacement as explained here: [link](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-1-5959aa49337c)