# Why the PreferenceScreen diaplays incorrectly in sdk version 28? How to solve it?

Tags: android, preferencescreen

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01"
implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:28.0.0-rc01"
```

This the code in my build.gradle.And I write a settings_pref.xml.It does not display corrently in Android Studio and my phone.

This is the settings_pref.xml.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/settings_about">

        <Preference
            android:title="@string/settings_version"
            app:key="version"
            android:summary="%s"/>

        <Preference
            android:title="@string/settings_rate"
            app:key="rate"
            android:summary="@string/settings_rate_desc"/>

        <Preference
            android:title="@string/settings_licenses"
            app:key="licenses"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/settings_thanks">
        <Preference
            android:title="@string/settings_lizhaotailang"
            app:key="lizhaotailang"
            android:summary="@string/settings_lizhaotailang_desc"/>
        <Preference
            android:title="@string/settings_hongyang"
            app:key="hongyang"
            android:summary="@string/settings_hongyang_desc"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/settings_support">
        <Preference
            android:title="@string/settings_source_code"
            app:key="source_code"
            android:summary="@string/settings_source_code_link"/>
        <Preference
            android:title="@string/settings_send_advices"
            app:key="send_advice"
            android:summary="@string/settings_send_advices_desc"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is the strings.xml

```
<!-- Settings start -->
    <string name="settings_about">About</string>
    <string name="settings_version">Version</string>
    <string name="settings_rate">Rate</string>
    <string name="settings_rate_desc">If you like this app, please do rate it.</string>
    <string name="settings_licenses">Licenses</string>
    <string name="settings_thanks">Thanks</string>
    <string name="settings_lizhaotailang">Li Zhao Tai Lang</string>
    <string name="settings_lizhaotailang_desc">Appreciate his help very much</string>
    <string name="settings_lizhaotailang_link">https://github.com/TonnyL</string>
    <string name="settings_hongyang">Hong Yang</string>
    <string name="settings_hongyang_desc">API provider</string>
    <string name="settings_hongyang_link">https://github.com/hongyangAndroid</string>
    <string name="settings_support">Support</string>
    <string name="settings_source_code">GitHub Source code</string>
    <string name="settings_source_code_link">https://xxxxxxx</string>
    <string name="settings_send_advices">Send advices</string>
    <string name="settings_send_advices_desc">Help me improve this app</string>
    <string name="settings_mail_account">mailto:719952215@qq.com</string>
    <string name="settings_device_model">Device Version:</string>
    <string name="settings_mail_topic">WanAndroid Advices</string>
    <string name="settings_sdk_version">SDK Version:</string>
    <!-- Settings end -->
```

[incorrect_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZRNM.jpg)

If I change the support library version, which is lower than 28.0.0, like this:

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:27.1.1"
```

It displays correctly.

[correct_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoFJ9.jpg)

What should I do to solve it? If I do not want to change my support library version: 28.0.0-rc01 ？

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your preferences XML file?

Comment: Yep, I have added my preferences XML file.

Comment: Might want to refer to this question. It helped me fix the spacing issue with version 28 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518758/preferencefragmentcompat-has-padding-on-preferencecategory-that-i-cant-get-rid