# Android: How to disable Reserved Icon Space in Preference Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-preferences

I have got a trouble with layout of Preference screen after updated SDK to version 28 (Android Pie). Each PreferenceScreen has a new padding on the left.

As I've checked, there is a method to set icon space as reserved in Preference class already.

```
android.support.v7.preference.Preference.setIconSpaceReserved(boolean iconSpaceReserved)
```

The method is good so far, but the problem is that it doesn't work with PreferenceCategory.

Does this mean that the left padding on PreferenceCategory is not a space for icon?

Comment: I solved by a workaround with styles. It works with PreferenceCategory. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52573593/5256040

Answer (score 9):

Solved using app:iconSpaceReserved="false" in the preference xml (under each item).

```
    <PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Pro Settings"
    app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
    >

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="plugin"
        android:title="@string/EnablePlugin"
        android:summary="@string/PluginDescription"
        android:id="@+id/Pref"
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
        />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 3):

it is a bug and already solved. you need to wait for the update

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111662669

Comment: A fix has now been released in androidx.preference 1.1.0-alpha01. I guess this means it will never be released in the com.android.support track.