# Preference library version 28 creates huge padding on the left side of each preference

Tags: android, android-layout

I updated the com.android.support:preference library from version 27 to 28 and ever since I did that, there is a huge amount of padding to the left of each preference. It's almost like it's assuming that there will be icons there, but I have no icons specified. See screenshot below. Is there a way to get rid of this padding?

[image: PreferenceScreen layout]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try set:

```
app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this before but I used the android namespace. Using the app namespace fixed it. However, this doesn't work on PreferenceCategory elements. Looks like I may have to use a custom style to fix the PreferenceCategory elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518758/preferencefragmentcompat-has-padding-on-preferencecategory-that-i-cant-get-rid/52573593#52573593

Comment: Or you could upgrade it to `1.1.0-alpha2` and put `app:iconSpaceReserved="false"` in `PreferenceCategory` https://stackoverflow.com/a/53285715/2559927