# PreferenceFragmentCompat has iconSpaceReserved true by default

Tags: android, android-preferences, androidx, preferencefragment

I've migrated to androidx.* libraries and one of them is the new preferences library:
`androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha01` - the latest version of it.

As said in [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn#2018-nov-preference) `iconSpaceReserved` attribute not working correctly with PreferenceCategories is fixed.

But looks like it's set to ***true*** by default.

I've built demo project to test it.

*PreferencesFragment*

```
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SetttingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

*preferences.xml*

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Category 1">
        <Preference
            android:key="pref1"
            android:title="Preference 1" />
        <Preference
            android:key="pref2"
            android:title="Preference 2" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Category 2"
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false">
        <Preference
            android:key="pref3"
            android:title="Preference 3" />
        <Preference
            android:key="pref4"
            android:title="Preference 4"
            app:iconSpaceReserved="false" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    ...
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Preferences theme is set as needed.

*styles.xml*

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
```

*Screenshot*

[image: PreferencesFragment]

When `app:iconSpaceReserved=false` is set manually (as you can see on PreferenceCategory 2 and Preference 4) it works fine, but otherwise a space for icon is reserved.
Also [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:iconSpaceReserved) says that it's `false` by default:

> By default, preference icon view visibility will be set to GONE when there is no icon provided, so the default value of this attribute is false.

Is it a new bug in this library or a new feature to leave space for icon if it's not set? Or am I doing something wrong?

I know about workarounds:

- [PreferenceFragmentCompat has padding on PreferenceCategory that I can't get rid of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518758/preferencefragmentcompat-has-padding-on-preferencecategory-that-i-cant-get-rid/52960668#52960668)
- [How to get remove margin/padding in Preference Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509369/android-how-to-get-remove-margin-padding-in-preference-screen)

---

**Edit:**

After looking through the sources I found the next thing.

`PreferenceThemeOverlay -> anyPreferenceStyle` has set the attribute

```
<item name="iconSpaceReserved">@bool/config_materialPreferenceIconSpaceReserved</item>
```

which refers to

```
values/values.xml
    <bool name="config_materialPreferenceIconSpaceReserved">false</bool>
```

and

```
values-sw360dp-v13/values-sw360dp-v13.xml
    <bool name="config_materialPreferenceIconSpaceReserved">true</bool>
```

For some reason it's set to `true` here.

Comment: I've not used that yet, but looking through the source, it seems `PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material` is deprecated – https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/preference/res/values/themes.xml#39. Try using `PreferenceThemeOverlay` instead. All of the styles in that theme have `iconSpaceReserved` set to `false` (actually, they're set to a `bool` resource value that's `false`).

Comment: @MikeM. thanks, forgot to check this. But nothing changed, padding is still there.

Comment: Well, I'm having machine issues, atm, and can't pull that to test. Have you tried to check the theme value of `iconSpaceReserved` at runtime, just to see if the resource value is wrong, or if it's an issue in the `Preference` classes?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the suggestion, done. When `iconSpaceReserved` is not set manually it returns `true` (for example, *Preference 1* on my screenshot), if set to `false` manually returns `false` (*Preference 4*) as expected. Tested it on my physical device with API 26 and on emulators with different APIs (including 28). Also Layout Inspector shows some padding.

Comment: Also see edit at the end of my question. `iconSpaceReserved` is `true` in `values-sw360dp-v13`, almost for all android devices. Looks like they forgot to change it to `false` in the library. I will check issue tracker and post new issue if I find nothing related.

Comment: I'm not seeing a `values-sw360dp-v13` bucket in the androidx repo. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/preference/res Do you have the source downloaded? I'm sure that's probably more up-to-date.

Comment: Ah, it is `true`, though, in `values-sw360dp`, so same diff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've [posted this on the Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119882818) and got the following answer:

> This is intended and part of the Material spec for Settings. See
> [Material Design guide](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-settings.html#label-secondary-text) under 'Alignment'.