# Android PreferenceScreen showing a lot of empty space on left side

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment, settings, android-preferences

Hello i have the following fragment which extends `PreferenceFragmentCompat`:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(){
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreatePreferences")
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences)
    }
...
}
```

The **xml** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Catogeory 1">

        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="key1"
            android:title="Switch Preference"
            android:summary="Switch Summary"
            android:defaultValue="true" />

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="key2"
            android:title="EditText Preference"
            android:summary="EditText Summary"
            android:dialogMessage="Dialog Message"
            android:defaultValue="Default value" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="key3"
            android:title="CheckBox Preference"
            android:summary="CheckBox Summary"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

in the preview it looks fine, but on my emulator, there is a lot of padding on the left side as seen here:

[image]

How do i make it so the text goes closer to the edge of the screen

Thanks

Comment: The AndroidX/Support library Preferences force a blank space to the start of the Preference. It's a reserved space for the icon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to remove margin/padding in Preference Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509369/android-how-to-remove-margin-padding-in-preference-screen)

Comment: @TheWanderer thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
```

use this attribute in `xml`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this question is a duplicate of [Android: How to remove margin/padding in Preference Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509369/android-how-to-remove-margin-padding-in-preference-screen) and [PreferenceFragmentCompat has padding on PreferenceCategory that I can't get rid of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518758/preferencefragmentcompat-has-padding-on-preferencecategory-that-i-cant-get-rid).

As Sah Rishabh as said, you can sort of fix this by adding

```
app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
```

to **every Preference tag** in the xml.

However, this is not a good solution as it doesn't really work with Preference Categories (the titles are still a bit too the right) and requires adding something to every single tag.

The best solution is therefore described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53969021/4588511) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52960668/4588511) (the same answer), as:

> Create `res/values-sw360dp-v13/values-preference.xml` containing:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
>     <bool name="config_materialPreferenceIconSpaceReserved" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource,PrivateResource">false</bool>
>     <dimen name="preference_category_padding_start" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource,PrivateResource">0dp</dimen>
> </resources>
> ```