# PreferenceFragmentCompat adds margin to preference items

Tags: android, androidx, preferencefragment

Consider this example:

There is a minimal activity in android which inflates this layout as root:

```
<!-- FILE activity_preference.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/settings_container"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the activity's onCreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_preference);
```

Then I want to replace *settings_container* with my [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat).
I'm using the current androidx Jetpack library, this goes into the app's gradle file:

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
```

I've also created a custom PreferenceFragmentCompat for my needs, but it does not really do too much now:

```
public class MyPreferenceFragmentCompat extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {   

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

        // get the screen
        PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(getContext());

        // add item(s)
        CheckBoxPreference  item_Confirmation;
        item_Confirmation = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
        item_Confirmation.setKey("config_Confirmation");
        item_Confirmation.setTitle("Confirmation");
        item_Confirmation.setSummary("Confirmation");
        item_Confirmation.setDefaultValue(false);
        preferenceScreen.addPreference(item_Confirmation);

        // set this screen as default
        setPreferenceScreen(preferenceScreen);
    }
```

Here is how activity transacts my fragment:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settings_container, new MyPreferenceFragmentCompat()).commit();
```

### However a wide margin gets inserted in front of the CheckboxItem:

[image]

### How can I eliminate this margin or padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **AndroidX**, you can use `Preference.setIconSpaceReserved(boolean iconSpaceReserved)` method.

So, you will have:

```
item_Confirmation.setIconSpaceReserved(false);
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52960668/8906488) answer.