# Remove Divider from Preference category

Tags: android, android-preferences

How can I remove dividers from preference category

```
<PreferenceCategory
            android:key="@string/pref_waking_category_key"
            android:title="@string/pref_waking_category_title">

            <SwitchPreference
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:key="@string/pref_waking_notify_key"
                android:title="@string/pref_waking_notify_title" />

            <com.kosratdahmad.myprayers.views.TimePreference
                android:defaultValue="@string/pref_waking_time_default"
                android:dependency="@string/pref_waking_notify_key"
                android:dialogTitle=""
                android:key="@string/pref_waking_time_key"
                android:title="@string/pref_waking_time_title" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I have looked this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750901/how-to-manage-dividers-in-a-preferencefragment) but I'm using PreferenceActivity instead PreferenceFragment.
I think my problem in getting view from preference category

Comment: why don't you use 'PreferenceFragment'

Comment: I have used one xml file for all settings preference and attached it in Preference Activity