# How to show divider in between preferences using PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a preference screen and inflated in a class extending PreferenceFragmentCompat. But the dividers in between the preference items are not showing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using **AndroidX**, add the following attributes to each of your preferences in XML:

```
<Preference
    ...
    app:allowDividerAbove="true"
    app:allowDividerBelow="true"
    ... />
```

You can also see a more detailed answer here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55981453/2836371)

Answer (score -1):

Wrap every 'Preference' with 'PreferenceCategory' tag to get divider between the preferences in your XML file

example:

```
<PreferenceCategory>
  <ListPreference ... />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: That’s the easiest way to do it, but leaves you with the TOP GAP of the category title space. Looking for another solution

Comment: You can use Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix at https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix . Take a look at the README markdown in the bottom of the page.