# PreferenceGroupAdapter can only be accessed from within the same library group

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the `PreferenceGroupAdapter` adapter on my `FragmentPreferenceCompat` without luck. I am using the the code from the following thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51832736

I get the message:

`PreferenceGroupAdapter can only be accessed from within the same library group`

Am I right to assume that this class was available at some point and they have decided to restrict it for internal use at a later stage? If that is the case, is there any way to access/iterate over the viewholders to perform a specific task.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think the class had restricted methods before.

`@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")` above the class fixes that for me.